# What is the keep_alive library and will it work?

Tags: discord.py

I saw a question for a discord bot and it was using a library called "keep_alive". How can I import it to my bot if it does keep the bot online?

Comment: ```keep_alive``` is not a library. It's a python file which is mentioned in the answer. Also be aware that repl.it is only recommended for hosting small-scale or private discord bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is the keep_alive code which prevents your repl from dying by creating a flask server. You should use [uptime-robot](https://uptimerobot.com/) to make the server gets pinged in a certain amount of time to make it work for long time without stopping.

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return "Your bot is alive!"

def run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    server = Thread(target=run)
    server.start()
```

You should create a keep_alive and paste the above code there and then add `keep_alive.keep_alive()` in your main file to make it work.

You can refer this [youtube-video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBwNQImv9Ek) to understand how to use that